# Passing data attribute to TextBoxFor not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor, html.textboxfor

I have the following code inside my ASP.NET MVC 4 razor view:

```
<div>
    <span class="f">Old Tag</span> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.olfTag, new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home") }) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.olfTag)          
</div>
```

But `data_autocomplete_source` with `TextBoxFor` will not work. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: define: will not work.

Comment: wll not work ,, means that the autocomplete data will not be shown !!

Comment: I think we need a bit more context to figure this one out.

Comment: ...did you include the relevant jQuery parts to make this work?  This is not a native HTML tag/call and requires more than just outputting a text box

Comment: Is the HTML rendered as you want? The problem may be somewhere else? Does your plugin or whatever throw an error?

Comment: @Hannele Please be careful with your edits.  You removed half of the question's title.

Comment: @JohnH My apologies, just realized. Will keep a closer eye.

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript should add the jquery autocomplete components to your control (and any control with the data-autocomplete-source attribute).

```
$(function() {

    var createAutoComplete = function() {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-autocomplete-source")
        };

        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };

    $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(createAutoComplete);
});
```